# select-string any string that matches content of other string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, expression

Here is my problem :

Say I have a first variable with the value :

```
$a = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

and another variable with :

```
$b = "This morning a hunter killed a fox."
```

The only word that is present in both string is the word fox.

The thing is, I have a collection of 2 arrays, both containing different strings.
I would like to know what words are present in both collections given that just like in my example above, a same word can match different strings so I can't simply run

```
$a | sls $b
```

because that wouldn't work as I need to use a regexp here but I don't know what regex to use in this context given that every single line in the 2 arrays are unique and any of the words in any line from the array $a could be in array $b.

Before I try to split every string using the space character between the words, and then compare every $split individually with the string from the other array, I was wondering if there's a handy regex expression or some select-string command that can do the job easily ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @MDMoore313 you need some replace to remove punctuations i.e. `$_.replace('.','')`

Give this a try:

```
 compare-object ( $a | % { $_ -split '\s+' } )  ( $b | % { $_ -split '\s+' } ) -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```

`$a` and `$b` are array of strings with words separed by spaces.

Comment: +1, I've never used compare-object, however it won't work without removing the punctuation from `$b`.

Comment: @MDMoore313 yes, good point! Add one way to remove it... before comparison.

Comment: That's not bad, I am getting closer with this! Now I only need to know which lines are matching. I already know that the same lines will be displayed in the output several times as we basically split the words using the space character, but then again a get-unique might just do the job afterwards! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to create a second regex to do the search. For example:

```
var $a = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
var $b = "This morning a hunter killed a fox.";

var r2 = new RegExp($a.replace(/\s/g,"|"), "g");
$b.match(r2);
```

Yields ["fox"]. (I realize you're probably using PHP -- the above is javascript.)

You would still have to compare every string in the array.

Comment: They are using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. A note, you probably want to implement stronger logic to remove punctuations.

```
$a = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

$b = "This morning a hunter killed a fox."

$a = $a.Remove($a.IndexOf("."),1)
$b = $b.Remove($b.IndexOf("."),1)

$c = $A.Split(" ")
$d = $B.Split(" ")

$c | foreach{
    $e = $_ 
    $d | foreach{ 
        $f = $_
        if($e -eq $f){
            Write-Host "$e`n"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The O.P. talk about string array [string[]] and not just [string]